# While making modules_install getting an error "No space left on device"

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, make

I'm using Ubuntu 20.4 LTS. I added a patch to the linux-5.4 kernel and followed below commands to complie it,

```
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make oldconfig
ccache make ARCH=i386
sudo make modules_install
```

It took about 8-10 hours to compile and when I try to make the modules_install, I'm seeing no space left message.

I took following steps found on StackOverflow to diagnose the issue,

1. Ran `du -sh` command and it outputs,

   `15G     .`
2. Ran `du -h` command and it outputs,

   ```
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   udev            448M     0  448M   0% /dev
   tmpfs            99M   12M   87M  12% /run
   /dev/sda         25G   25G     0 100% /
   tmpfs           491M     0  491M   0% /dev/shm
   tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
   tmpfs           491M     0  491M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   ```
3. Ran `lsof | grep deleted` command and it outputs nothing
4. Ran `df -i` command and it outputs,

   ```
   Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
   udev            114642    367  114275    1% /dev
   tmpfs           125596    501  125095    1% /run
   /dev/sda       1568000 320966 1247034   21% /
   tmpfs           125596      4  125592    1% /dev/shm
   tmpfs           125596      3  125593    1% /run/lock
   tmpfs           125596     18  125578    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
   ```
5. Finally, I ran `sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda`and rebooted the server but the error still there
6. Ran `sudo du -x / | sort -n | tail -50` and here is the output from it,

```
288224  /root/.conan/data/project1stuff
288948  /root/.conan/data
289348  /root/.conan
291712  /home/linux-5.4/drivers/infiniband
295732  /root/.ccache/3
298872  /home/linux-5.4/sound/soc
300136  /home/chris/project1/source/Dist
300684  /root/.ccache/8
300996  /root/.ccache/5
303284  /root/.ccache/c
305472  /root/.ccache/7
308620  /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0/kernel/drivers/media
312200  /home/linux-5.4/arch
349576  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
358224  /var/log/journal/98934a16ea8846759c9ae817caf8c438
358228  /var/log/journal
361268  /home/linux-5.4/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu
386436  /home/linux-5.4/drivers/scsi
441516  /var/log
452736  /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm
452740  /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0/kernel/drivers/gpu
483996  /home/linux-5.4/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau
525444  /home/linux-5.4/drivers/staging
529596  /usr/lib/firmware
616428  /home/linux-5.4/drivers/gpu/drm/amd
627008  /home/linux-5.4/sound
850876  /var
902680  /home/linux-5.4/drivers/media
913128  /home/chris/project1/source
920664  /home/linux-5.4/fs
921180  /home/chris/project1
1023064 /home/linux-5.4/drivers/net/ethernet
1033372 /home/chris
1067620 /home/linux-5.4/drivers/net/wireless
1411676 /home/linux-5.4/net
1618588 /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0/kernel/drivers
1659620 /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0/kernel
1659904 /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0
1664808 /home/linux-5.4/drivers/gpu/drm
1666220 /home/linux-5.4/drivers/gpu
1927408 /usr/lib/modules
2427396 /home/linux-5.4/drivers/net
3252368 /usr/lib
4006852 /usr
4294576 /root/.ccache
4700716 /root
8790276 /home/linux-5.4/drivers
14319228        /home/linux-5.4
15533372        /home
25200780        /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df -h` (not du -h as you wrote) indicates you have no free space left.

The following command will let you see where the space has gone:

```
sudo du -x / | sort -n | tail -50
```

**Edit:**

You're running low on space.

`/home/linux-5.4` occupies around `14GB`

`/root/.ccache` occupies around `4GB` - you can safely `sudo rm -rf /root/.ccache` but I'm not sure that will be enough. Please don't use ccache going forward if you have no space at all.

Comment: Please see my edit for the output for this command. I'm not sure what to do at this point aka which file would be safe to delete.

Comment: But why /home/linux-5.4 need full space?

Comment: It looks like you're compiling the entire kernel and all its modules. That indeed requires a lot of space. The kernel source tree alone weighs in at over 1GB.

Comment: I could delete .ccache (Planed to use it to speed up further complications) but still don't know why /home/linux-5.4 source code that 14GB just for the damn source code..

Comment: Oh I see. Is there way to compile only necessary patch? I was using Medium tutorial.

Comment: `make help` could give you an idea how to compile individual kernel modules or just vmlinuz.

Comment: Thank you. I will delete ccache for now and in next time will compile only module.